# show data from json with vue.js

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

Hi am trying to show some data from json with vue.js 
this is my vue file:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                  <h4 class="card-title">Customer Infos</h4>
            </div>      
            <div class="card-content">
             {{site}}
            </div>      
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        props: ['site'],
        mounted () {
            console.dir(this.site)
        }
    }
</script>
<style>
</style>
```

and this is the result:

```
{"id":274292982,"site_id":"2512016716"}}
```

i want to make it only show `site_id`

i have already tried this:

```
 {{site.site_id}}
```

no success. thanks you.

Comment: There's one too many ending curly braces in {"id":274292982,"site_id":"2512016716"}}

Comment: @cjs1978 it was copie past mistake

Comment: Do you get any console error?

Comment: @ittus no error

Comment: please provide some code about parent component - how you pass `site` data to child

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
computed: {
siteObject() {
    return JSON.parse(this.site);
}
```

after

```
{{ siteObject.site_id }}
```

Comment: Please add some meaningful explanation.